# Horizontal gene transfer in a bacteria

Tags: molecular-biology, bacteriology

I encountered an old examination question:

> Which of the following is not required in Bacteria for horizontal gene transfers?
>
> 1. Infection 2. Translation 3. Transformation 4. Conjugation 5. Transduction

Clearly this is aimed at testing an understanding of horizontal gene transfer. So far I have tried to think about it in the following terms:

A **horizontal gene transfer** is defined as “obtaining DNA” which doesn‘t stem from the original cell line.

**Transformation** is the intake of DNA, **Transduction** is the transfer between two bacteria over a phage, **conjugation** is like sex (?) between two bacteria. All these would seem to be needed.

However, during Conjugation, a bacterium translates/produces new DNA, so **translation** would also seem to be needed.

In this case all five items listed would seem to be required. Is this correct?

Comment: I have edited your question to make it of more general relevance, focusing on the process of horizontal gene transfer. Your definition of horizontal gene transfer is fuzzy, and you need to find a text book that describes it in detail, checking against the five processes in the question. You only define three of them and your implicit assumption about translation is incorrect. You can edit your question after doing more work.

Comment: There's a difference between being technically correct and getting the correct answer on an exam. Yes, theoretically transcription and translation need to occur for the formation of a conjugation pillus, but it's a stretch. That's the only answer that isn't *directly* related to transfer or uptake of genetic material. If you really want to be technically correct, none of the answers are "required" since that specific word choice would imply they are necessary in every instance of HGT.

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal gene transfer (HGT) is the transfer of genomic information between two already living cells. It is most known in Bacteria but happens also in Fungi (look for Ug99).
In bacteria the genetic information can come from the genome, a plasmid or from random dna or rna strains.
Transformation, Transduction and Conjugation are different kind of mechanisms. You should research them for better understanding.
I guess that by infection they mean infection by a bacteriophage which is a way of HGT.
Translation is the process of synthesize proteins from mRNA
This process is independent of HGT and therefore the right answer to the question.

As far as I know all the mechanisms needed for conjugation (the genomic material, pili and other cellular apparatus) are already present in the donor cell and therefore translation isn't needed. I belive you are confusing translation with transcription (creating RNA from DNA) but that isn't needed either as the plasmids containing the F-factor already exists.